# Do 0402 chip component need solder mask web between the pads?

Tags: bridge, reflow, solder-mask, dfm

In my board, all 0402 parts are using gang solder mask.

The pad to pad distance is 10 mils. Is there any risk of solder short?

Do I need to suggest applying solder mask web between the pads for all 0402?

[image]

Comment: What does your preferred PCB manufacturer advise?

Comment: Agreed with @Andyaka, you'd want to find out directly from your PCB manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Mentor Graphics  LP viewer based on IPC has the nominal pad edges just 0.39 mm apart for a RESC1005X40N. Our normal target is a 0.1 mm gap for copper pad to the resist, I reduced this to 0.0957 mm for my 0402 to maintain a 0.2 mm resist sliver.

Just my solution of course.